# JOGL not displaying

Tags: jogl

I'm hunting for an openGL library that'll work on both Macs & IBMs.  JOGL seems a good bet however, when I imported the JGears demo, I'm getting an odd result. All the swing related components in the program are displaying but the GLJPanel (being passed to an Animator) is not showing up.  As far as I can tell, the display method isn't being called at all.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm using JDK 1.7, and the latest jogl.jar and jogl-natives-macosx-universal.jar

Comment: how are you setting the display method up?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use NEWT for maximum compatibility as of today:

https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-2

However there are other advantages and disadvantages of Newt over Canvas, see the aforementioned link for the full list.

Moreover, try this Gears demo instead:

http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/jogl-demos/jogl-newt-applet-runner-gears.html

it should be what you were looking for from the beginning.